# how to condense consecutive duplicate rows in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

In a mysql database, how can I condense all consecutive duplicates into 1 while maintaining order in a select output?

#### data:

```
id  fruit
----------
1   Apple
2   Banana
3   Banana
4   Banana
5   Apple
6   Mango
7   Mango
8   Apple
```

Output I want:

```
fruit
-------
Apple
Banana
Apple
Mango
Apple
```

This is a very easy thing to do in unix with the uniq command, but 'distinct' is not as flexible.
IDs are not sequential, and gaps are possible.  I was oversimplifying in my example.
Select could be like this:

#### data:

```
id  fruit
----------
100  Apple
2    Banana
30   Banana
11   Banana
50   Apple
62   Mango
7    Mango
4    Apple
```

Comment: Please keep in mind, that unless stated explicitly (via ORDER BY), the result set has got **no particular order**. How (on what criteria) is your updated example is supposed to be ordered?

Answer (score 1):

Try this - assuming consecutive IDs with no gaps.

```
SELECT T.fruit
FROM YOURTABLE T
LEFT JOIN YOURTABLE T2
ON T2.ID = T.ID + 1
WHERE T2.fruit <> T.fruit
OR T2.ID IS NULL
ORDER BY T.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
  SELECT x.fruit
    FROM (SELECT t.fruit,
                 CASE 
                   WHEN @fruit <> t.fruit THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
                   ELSE @rownum
                 END as rank
            FROM YOUR_TABLE t
            JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @fruit := NULL) r
        ORDER BY t.id) x
GROUP BY x.fruit, x.rank
ORDER BY x.rank
```